# Fold over a partial list

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, fold, meta-predicate

This is a question provoked by an already deleted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462366/how-can-i-determine-that-all-given-coordinates-of-matrix-are-connected). The issue could be summarized as follows:

> Is it possible to fold over a list, with the tail of the list generated while folding?

Here is what I mean. Say I want to calculate the factorial (this is a silly example but it is just for demonstration), and decide to do it like this:

```
fac_a(N, F) :-
        must_be(nonneg, N),
        (       N =< 1
        ->      F = 1
        ;       numlist(2, N, [H|T]),
                foldl(multiplication, T, H, F)
        ).

multiplication(X, Y, Z) :-
        Z is Y * X.
```

Here, I need to generate the list that I give to `foldl`. However, I could do the same in constant memory (without generating the list and without using `foldl`):

```
fac_b(N, F) :-
        must_be(nonneg, N),
        (       N =< 1
        ->      F = 1
        ;       fac_b_1(2, N, 2, F)
        ).

fac_b_1(X, N, Acc, F) :-
        (       X < N
        ->      succ(X, X1),
                Acc1 is X1 * Acc,
                fac_b_1(X1, N, Acc1, F)
        ;       Acc = F
        ).
```

The point here is that unlike the solution that uses `foldl`, this uses constant memory: no need for generating a list with all values!

Calculating a factorial is not the best example, but it is easier to follow for the stupidity that comes next.

Let's say that I am really afraid of loops (and recursion), and insist on calculating the factorial using a fold. I still would need a list, though. So here is what I might try:

```
fac_c(N, F) :-
        must_be(nonneg, N),
        (       N =< 1
        ->      F = 1
        ;       foldl(fac_foldl(N), [2|Back], 2-Back, F-[])
        ).

fac_foldl(N, X, Acc-Back, F-Rest) :-
        (       X < N
        ->      succ(X, X1),
                F is Acc * X1,
                Back = [X1|Rest]
        ;       Acc = F,
                Back = []
        ).
```

To my surprise, this works as intended. I can "seed" the fold with an initial value at the head of a partial list, and keep on adding the next element as I consume the current head. The definition of `fac_foldl/4` is almost identical to the definition of `fac_b_1/4` above: the only difference is that the state is maintained differently. My assumption here is that this should use constant memory: **is that assumption wrong?**

I know this is silly, but it could however be useful for folding over a list that cannot be known when the fold starts. In the original question we had to find a connected region, given a list of x-y coordinates. It is not enough to fold over the list of x-y coordinates once (you can however [do it in two passes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Two-pass); note that there is at least [one better way to do it](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1077314202000309), referenced in the same Wikipedia article, but this also uses multiple passes; altogether, the multiple-pass algorithms assume constant-time access to neighboring pixels!).

My [own solution to the original "regions" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463442/1812457) looks something like this:

```
set_region_rest([A|As], Region, Rest) :-
        sort([A|As], [B|Bs]),
        open_set_closed_rest([B], Bs, Region0, Rest),
        sort(Region0, Region).

open_set_closed_rest([], Rest, [], Rest).
open_set_closed_rest([X-Y|As], Set, [X-Y|Closed0], Rest) :-
        X0 is X-1, X1 is X + 1,
        Y0 is Y-1, Y1 is Y + 1,
        ord_intersection([X0-Y,X-Y0,X-Y1,X1-Y], Set, New, Set0),
        append(New, As, Open),
        open_set_closed_rest(Open, Set0, Closed0, Rest).
```

Using the same "technique" as above, we can twist this into a fold:

```
set_region_rest_foldl([A|As], Region, Rest) :-
        sort([A|As], [B|Bs]),
        foldl(region_foldl, [B|Back],
                            closed_rest(Region0, Bs)-Back,
                            closed_rest([], Rest)-[]),
        !,
        sort(Region0, Region).

region_foldl(X-Y,
             closed_rest([X-Y|Closed0], Set)-Back,
             closed_rest(Closed0, Set0)-Back0) :-
        X0 is X-1, X1 is X + 1,
        Y0 is Y-1, Y1 is Y + 1,
        ord_intersection([X0-Y,X-Y0,X-Y1,X1-Y], Set, New, Set0),
        append(New, Back0, Back).
```

This also "works". The fold leaves behind a choice point, because I haven't articulated the end condition as in `fac_foldl/4` above, so I need a cut right after it (ugly).

### The Questions

- Is there a clean way of closing the list and removing the cut? In the factorial example, we know when to stop because we have additional information; however, in the second example, how do we notice that the back of the list should be the empty list?
- Is there a hidden problem I am missing?
- This looks like its somehow similar to the Implicit State with DCGs, but I have to admit I never quite got how that works; are these connected?

Comment: Oops, wasn't paying attention. Thought he means the question was deleted.

Comment: This is a SWI-Prolog specific question. It assumes predicates that are neither standard built-in predicates or standard library predicates such as `must_be/2` and `foldl/4`. They aren't even de facto standard predicates. I would re-add the `swi-prolog` tag but users that like to pretend otherwise would simply delete again. Politics instead of facts. Sad.

Comment: @PauloMoura I agree with you and have added the tag. Too many times have I seen the [swi-prolog] tag deleted from questions that I didn't even want to bother putting it there in the first place. I didn't know, for example, that `must_be/2` and `foldl/4` are SWI-Prolog specific :/

Comment: How is "fold over a partial list" SWI-specific? `foldl/4` is definitely **not** SWI-specific. It even appears in Richard O'Keefe's library proposal. Any beginner can implement it in any Prolog system. The [tag:swi-prolog] tag should be reserved for questions that are clearly SWI-specific, so that users find these pertaining questions more easily. Tagging everything where a single predicate that is provided by SWI is used anywhere as "SWI" makes it impossible to find such instances.

Comment: @mat I was just reading [the same](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pllib.htm): see down for "Higher order list predicates". `foldl/4` is right there. `must_be/2`, however, isn't. Is it in a standard?

Comment: `must_be/2` is definitely not the final word on type checking. SICStus provides a more general [**`must_be/4`**](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dtypes.html#lib_002dtypes). Progress in this area is slow, exacerbated by the tendency to regard already the slightest improvements in this area as "specific" to a system instead of encouraging other systems to adopt them. I remember years ago when I used `maplist/3`, people were quick to point out "that's not really Prolog". Now at least we have advanced to the same point being made only about `foldl/4`.

Comment: @Boris I know that you're aware of this recurring issue. Thanks for re-adding the tag.

Comment: @mat Prolog code that can only be run as-is in a *single* Prolog system, is specific to that system. Anyone trying to execute the code in any other system will get errors. Having a predicate specified in some proposal doesn't make it a standard, specially with something like `fold/4` where you have more than one sensible argument order.

Comment: I can only say again that adding this tag everywhere a predicate that is provided by SWI-Prolog is used in passing, especially if it can be implemented in any conforming system, makes it impossible to find the questions that are actually SWI-specific. There are plenty of such questions, since SWI provides nonconforming features that can **not** easily be implemented in conforming Prolog systems. `foldl/4` and `must_be/2` are definitely *not* such features. The main point of this question applies to all Prolog systems, whether they provide `must_be/2` or not, and is in no way SWI specific.

Comment: @mat the way i see it, if whoever writes the question is using a particular prolog implementation, they just tag both. Apparently not everyone agrees.

Comment: I know that this often happens. However, please read the documentation about the tags: They are meant to make *future* searches over questions easier, *not* to indicate the poster's particular situation. Only with the latter view, tagging the user's system makes sense, but it makes no sense with the way the tag system is meant to work on this page. Future readers should have it easy to quickly find pertaining questions to their system. Cluttering their tags with unrelated questions makes it much harder for them to filter the relevant questions.

Comment: @mat Future readers should not be forced into trial and error when finding answers with only a *generic* "prolog" tag that happen to only work on a specific system. A nasty consequence is users thinking that the Prolog system they are used is *broken* because it cannot run those supposedly generic answers. Another nasty consequence, also common in SO, is users, even advanced ones, thinking some predicate is a standard built-in predicate when it happens to be a library predicate that is far from being standard (official or de facto) across Prolog systems.

Comment: I can only say that a constructive solution would be to get predicates such as `maplist/3` and `foldl/4`, which have been *for years* included in Richard's library draft, **included** in other systems too. It is hindering progress to act for decades as if such features are somehow extremely esoteric and on the same level as non-conformant language features that some implementations provide. In my view, it is for the latter parts and other idiosyncrasies as well as implementation-defined extensions that the system-specific tags should be reserved. Other code runs with any conforming system.

Comment: @mat I do support such constructive solution. That's why I have made those meta-predicates and others, together with an optimizing compiler, available for most Prolog systems actively maintained. And I did that *years* before any implementation derived from Richard's library proposal.

Comment: That's great! Thank you! Personally, I think that when a solution that shows up here does not work with a particular system, it may also produce a good effect on Prolog systems because the pressure from users to make such features available may become higher. I agree that it is inconvenient for users to try code they find online and seeing it does not work on their system. However, I hope that this is only a comparatively short transitional period in which we see such predicates confined to only a few systems. For this reason, I use many features even if a question is not tagged with a system.

Answer (score 3):

You are touching on several extremely interesting aspects of Prolog, each well worth *several* separate questions on its own. I will provide a high-level answer to your actual questions, and hope that you post follow-up questions on the points that are most interesting to you.

First, I will trim down the fragment to its essence:

```
essence(N) :-
        foldl(essence_(N), [2|Back], Back, _).

essence_(N, X0, Back, Rest) :-
        (   X0 #< N ->
            X1 #= X0 + 1,
            Back = [X1|Rest]
        ;   Back = []
        ).
```

Note that this prevents the creation of extremely large integers, so that we can really study the memory behaviour of this pattern.

To your first question: **Yes**, this runs in **O(1)** space (assuming constant space for arising integers).

*Why?* Because although you continuously create lists in `Back = [X1|Rest]`, these lists can all be readily **garbage collected** because you are not referencing them anywhere.

To test memory aspects of your program, consider for example the following query, and limit the global stack of your Prolog system so that you can quickly detect growing memory by running out of (global) stack:

```
?- length(_, E),
   N #= 2^E,
   portray_clause(N),
   essence(N),
   false.
```

This yields:

```
1.
2.
...
8388608.
16777216.
etc.
```

It would be **completely** different if you *referenced* the list somewhere. For example:

```
essence(N) :-
        foldl(essence_(N), [2|Back], Back, _),
        Back = [].
```

With this very small change, the above query yields:

```
?- length(_, E),
   N #= 2^E,
   portray_clause(N),
   essence(N),
   false.
1.
2.
...
1048576.
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Thus, whether a term is referenced somewhere can significantly influence the memory requirements of your program. This sounds quite frightening, but really is hardly an issue in practice: You either need the term, in which case you need to represent it in memory anyway, or you don't need the term, in which case it is simply no longer referenced in your program and becomes amenable to garbage collection. In fact, the amazing thing is rather that GC works so well in Prolog also for quite complex programs that not much needs to be said about it in many situations.

---

On to your second question: Clearly, using `(->)/2` is almost always highly problematic in that it limits you to a particular direction of use, destroying the generality we expect from logical relations.

There are several solutions for this. If your CLP(FD) system supports `zcompare/3` or a similar feature, you can write `essence_/3` as follows:

```
essence_(N, X0, Back, Rest) :-
        zcompare(C, X0, N),
        closing(C, X0, Back, Rest).

closing(<, X0, [X1|Rest], Rest) :- X1 #= X0 + 1.
closing(=, _, [], _).
```

Another very nice meta-predicate called **`if_/3`** was recently introduced in [**Indexing dif/2**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590) by Ulrich Neumerkel and Stefan Kral. I leave implementing this with `if_/3` as a very worthwhile and instructive exercise. Discussing this is *well worth its own question*!

---

On to the third question: How do states with DCGs relate to this? DCG notation is definitely useful if you want to pass around a global state to several predicates, where only a few of them need to access or modify the state, and most of them simply pass the state through. This is completely analogous to **monads** in Haskell.

The "normal" Prolog solution would be to extend each predicate with 2 arguments to describe the relation between the state before the call of the predicate, and the state after it. DCG notation lets you avoid this hassle.

Importantly, using DCG notation, you can copy imperative algorithms almost verbatim to Prolog, without the hassle of introducing many auxiliary arguments, even if you need global states. As an example for this, consider a fragment of Tarjan's [**strongly connected components**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) algorithm in imperative terms:

```
  function strongconnect(v)
    // Set the depth index for v to the smallest unused index
    v.index := index
    v.lowlink := index
    index := index + 1
    S.push(v)
```

This clearly makes use of a global **stack** and **index**, which ordinarily would become new arguments that you need to pass around in *all* your predicates. Not so with DCG notation! For the moment, assume that the global entities are simply easily accessible, and so you can code the whole fragment in Prolog as:

```
scc_(V) -->
        vindex_is_index(V),
        vlowlink_is_index(V),
        index_plus_one,
        s_push(V),
```

*This is a very good candidate for its own question*, so consider this a teaser.

---

At last, I have a general remark: In my view, we are only *at the beginning* of finding a series of very powerful and general meta-predicates, and the solution space is still largely *unexplored*. `call/N`, `maplist/[3,4]`, `foldl/4` and other meta-predicates are definitely a good start. `if_/3` has the potential to combine good performance with the generality we expect from Prolog predicates.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer to a somewhat rambling question. Now, the only practical problem I have with my weird use of `foldl` comes from the end condition, in the sense that I am not sure _what_ it is. When the first argument to `foldl` is a proper list, the end condition is "list is empty". In the first example (factorial) and in your "essence" example we have an additional argument that articulates what the end condition is. However, in the "region" example the end condition is "list is empty".... Do you see the circular logic there?

Comment: I interpreted the question "is there a clean way of closing the list without using a cut" to apply to the factorial example, where it *also* is not clean because you are impurely committing to one branch of the condition even if both branches can logically apply (try it with more general queries). Admittedly it is more local than using `!/0`, but still quite bad because it undercuts the generality of your code. As we are discussing so many issues in this question, I would prefer to see the "what is a good meta-predicate for the region example" factored out in its own question, with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If your Prolog implementation supports **freeze/2** or similar predicate (e.g. Swi-Prolog), then you can use following approach:

```
fac_list(L, N, Max) :-
    (N >= Max, L = [Max], !)
    ;
    freeze(L, (
        L = [N|Rest],
        N2 is N + 1,
        fac_list(Rest, N2, Max)
    )).

multiplication(X, Y, Z) :-
    Z is Y * X.

factorial(N, Factorial) :-
    fac_list(L, 1, N),
    foldl(multiplication, L, 1, Factorial).
```

Example above first defines a predicate (**fac_list**) which creates a "lazy" list of increasing integer values starting from N up to maximum value (Max), where next list element is generated only after previous one was "accessed" (more on that below). Then, **factorial** just folds **multiplication** over lazy list, resulting in constant memory usage.

The key to understanding how this example works is remembering that Prolog lists are, in fact, just terms of arity 2 with name '.' (actually, in Swi-Prolog 7 the name was changed, but this is not important for this discussion), where first element represents list item and the second element represents tail (or terminating element - empty list, []). For example. [1, 2, 3] can be represented as:

```
.(1, .(2, .(3, [])))
```

Then, **freeze** is defined as follows:

```
freeze(+Var, :Goal)
    Delay the execution of Goal until Var is bound
```

This means if we call:

```
freeze(L, L=[1|Tail]), L = [A|Rest].
```

then following steps will happen:

1. **freeze(L, L=[1|Tail])** is called
2. Prolog "remembers" that when **L** will be unified with "anything", it needs to call **L=[1|Tail]**
3. **L = [A|Rest]** is called
4. Prolog unifies **L** with **.(A, Rest)**
5. This unification triggers execution of **L=[1|Tail]**
6. This, obviously, unifies **L**, which at this point is bound to **.(A, Rest)**, with **.(1, Tail)**
7. As a result, **A** gets unified with 1.

We can extend this example as follows:

```
freeze(L1, L1=[1|L2]),
freeze(L2, L2=[2|L3]),
freeze(L3, L3=[3]),
L1 = [A|R2], % L1=[1|L2] is called at this point
R2 = [B|R3], % L2=[2|L3] is called at this point
R3 = [C].    % L3=[3] is called at this point
```

This works exactly like the previous example, except that it gradually generates 3 elements, instead of 1.

Comment: How about the second example from my question? The factorial is just a proof of principle, and a poorly chosen one. The second example has a real problem as it stands now (I don't know how to know when to close the list), and I still am not sure how to deal with it. Does `freeze` help?

Answer (score 0):

As per Boris's request, the second example implemented using **freeze**. Honestly, I'm not quite sure whether this answers the question, as the code (and, IMO, the problem) is rather contrived, but here it is. At least I hope this will give other people the idea what freeze might be useful for. For simplicity, I am using 1D problem instead of 2D, but changing the code to use 2 coordinates should be rather trivial.

The general idea is to have (1) function that generates new Open/Closed/Rest/etc. state based on previous one, (2) "infinite" list generator which can be told to "stop" generating new elements from the "outside", and (3) fold_step function which folds over "infinite" list, generating new state on each list item and, if that state is considered to be the last one, tells generator to halt.

It is worth to note that list's elements are used for no other reason but to inform generator to stop. All calculation state is stored inside accumulator.

**Boris**, please clarify whether this gives a solution to your problem. More precisely, what kind of data you were trying to pass to fold step handler (Item, Accumulator, Next Accumulator)?

```
adjacent(X, Y) :-
    succ(X, Y) ;
    succ(Y, X).

state_seq(State, L) :-
    (State == halt -> L = [], !)
    ;
    freeze(L, (
        L = [H|T],
        freeze(H, state_seq(H, T))
    )).

fold_step(Item, Acc, NewAcc) :-
    next_state(Acc, NewAcc),
    NewAcc = _:_:_:NewRest,
    (var(NewRest) ->
        Item = next ;
        Item = halt
    ).

next_state(Open:Set:Region:_Rest, NewOpen:NewSet:NewRegion:NewRest) :-
    Open = [],
    NewOpen = Open,
    NewSet = Set,
    NewRegion = Region,
    NewRest = Set.

next_state(Open:Set:Region:Rest, NewOpen:NewSet:NewRegion:NewRest) :-
    Open = [H|T],
    partition(adjacent(H), Set, Adjacent, NotAdjacent),
    append(Adjacent, T, NewOpen),
    NewSet = NotAdjacent,
    NewRegion = [H|Region],
    NewRest = Rest.

set_region_rest(Ns, Region, Rest) :-
    Ns = [H|T],
    state_seq(next, L),
    foldl(fold_step, L, [H]:T:[]:_, _:_:Region:Rest).
```

One fine improvement to the code above would be making fold_step a higher order function, passing it next_state as the first argument.

Comment: It will take me a while to carefully read and use your example because I am busy with other things right now, but I will get to it and let you know.